# gpg2.exe and gpg.exe exit code 255

Tags: gnupg

I have the following system configuration:

Windows 2008 Server 64-bit with Service Pack 1

Gpg4win, version 2.1.0

Included Gpg4win components in Version 2.1.0 are:

```
GnuPG:          2.0.17
Kleopatra:      2.1.0 (2011-02-04)
GPA:            0.9.1-svn1024
GpgOL:          1.1.2
GpgEX:          0.9.7
Claws-Mail:     3.7.8cvs47
Kompendium DE:  3.0.0
Kompendium EN:  3.0.0-beta1
```

What I'm trying to do is to decrypt a local file using GnuPG with Process.Start from a .NET 3.5 web service.

This command below is working just fine when ran from cmd.exe on that very machine.

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub\" --charset utf8 --no-tty --output c:\decrypted_file.txt" --batch -r "name_for_secret_key" 
--passphrase-file "C:\path_to_passphrase_file.txt" 
--decrypt "c:\encrypted_file.gpg"`

However it's not working when executed from the web service that is deployed under IIS 7.5.
Tried the following:

```
- impersonated user with admin rights (in the application pool or in the code itself) to run the process under
- ran the cmd.exe process directly with Process.Start and passed in the arguments as described above (by redirecting standard input)
```

Results

```
- exit code for gpg2.exe is 255 and nothing else happened
- in event viewer / application found errors like: Faulting application gpg2.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x4d6e6194, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x00000000, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00000000, process id 0x1a914, application start time 0x01cd3f46059b0031.
- by redirecting standarderror I only got the same 255 exit code
- ran Process Monitor on that machine but that hasn't helped either, there were some "Name Not Found" issues, no access denied problems and both gpg.exe and gpg2.exe results were SUCCESS and exit codes were 255.
- DEP has default settings, it's on on essential windows programs and services
```

Could you think of something different than what I've already tried which might get this working?